# How to get the name of the content of a Texture2D xna

Tags: c#, xna, filenames, texture2d

I'm developing a game in xna and I need to get the name of the content of a texture2d to know if the one pressed is the right one due to the fact that they will be charged random
For example

```
      repeat= Content.Load<Texture2D>("repeat");
```

I will need something that later tells me that the name of the content of the texture 2d is "repeat"
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what you're asking is:

```
repeat.Name.ToString();
```

but it makes literally zero sense to do that. You've already named the Texture2D 'repeat'?

If you're changing images randomly then load all of the textures and then just draw the one thats been randomly selected:

```
 repeat = Content.Load<Texture2D>("repeat");
 repeat1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("repeat1");
 repeat2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("repeat2");

public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
SpriteBatch.Begin();
if (random == 0)
{
SpriteBatch.Draw(repeat, Position, Color);
}
else if (random == 1)
{
SpriteBatch.Draw(repeat1, Position, Color);
}
else if (random == 2)
{
SpriteBatch.Draw(repeat2, Position, Color);
}
SpriteBatch.End();
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: And what if I have an array? How can I identifie the item for what it has?

Comment: Same way you'd do any other array, something like this:

for (int i = 0; i < textureArray.Count; i++)
{
 string name = textureArray[i].Name.ToString(); // Get name of Texture.

if (name == "TheNameIWant")
{
//Do Something
}
}